# SQL code generation from OdbcCommand Parameters collection in ADO.NET

Tags: sql, ado.net, odbc

When I create an OdbcCommand and add parameters, parameters that are of VarChar 4000 are translated into text type in generated sql. My sample code is:

```
OdbcConnection dbConnection = new OdbcConnection("DSN=database;UID=uid;PWD=pwd;");
try
{
    dbConnection.Open();
    OdbcCommand odbcCommand = new OdbcCommand();
    odbcCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE Table SET Notes = ? WHERE Notes = ?";
    odbcCommand.Connection = dbConnection;
    odbcCommand.Parameters.Add("", OdbcType.VarChar, 3999, "");
    odbcCommand.Parameters.Add("", OdbcType.VarChar, 4000, "");
    odbcCommand.Parameters[0].Value = "0";
    odbcCommand.Parameters[1].Value = "1";
    odbcCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
finally
{
    dbConnection.Close();
}
```

This is the generated SQL, that I got from SQL Server Profiler

```
exec sp_executesql N'UPDATE Table SET Notes = @P1 WHERE Notes = @P2',N'@P1 varchar(3999),@P2 text','0','1'
```

Even though MSDN does not say anything about maximum sizes for VarChar [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/yy6y35y8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Does anyone know why this happens and if this is configurable?
I believe it's a OdbcCommand specific thing because the update SQL statement that Simple Data generates for other field that is stored as varchar(4000) in the SQL Server database is generated correctly.

Comment: The solution was to switch to 3999 size field instead of 4000. This satisfies requirements and purpose of the change.

Answer (score 0):

VARCHAR with 4000 bytes will convert the stringsize to extented which will return text.

32767 bytes if MAX_STRING_SIZE = EXTENDED

4000 bytes if MAX_STRING_SIZE = STANDARD

I dont think you can change that.. so If you can post what you are trying to accomplish; that would be helpfull

Comment: Is it in SQL Server or ADO.NET? And how to change it? I'm talking about SQL Server, and the answer you've posted is related to Oracle I guess. And it is equal to 4000, not longer than 4000, so it should accept 4000 normally.

Comment: It's a legacy code and the task was to temporary lengthen the field size. The parameters are added like I show in sample code, so to change parameter size from 2000 to 4000 shouldn't be a problem, but then this strange varchar/text parameter conversion in generated occured and an error when updating: "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server] The data types text and varchar are incompatible in the equal to operator." from this error I found out that generated SQL statement has incorrect parameter type set to text instead of varchar(4000)